# Vertica Licensing Audit

Tags: vertica

Does anyone know what happens if a HP Vertica audit reveals higher than licensed usage? (Not by a whole lot, just a little -- Was contacted by HP just wondering what the fall out may be).

Not really experienced with here, just looking for any past experiences, any guidance here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing will happen. HP will ask you to purchase additional license or delete data to be compliant. Consider upgrading to 7.1.2 if you haven't already. There were [license audit changes](http://vertica.tips/2015/07/27/license-audit-calculation-in-7-1-2/) which will reduce your license usage.

Be aware that HP can perform an on-site audit anytime they please.

Set up monitoring for license usage if you haven't already.